# Second Django Logout Does Not Work

Tags: django, django-views

I'm currently trying to get my Django login/logout to work correctly, but am having a problem after I have logged in and logged out once. If I log in again as the same user or as a different user, I can no longer logout again. I am curious if anybody has ever experienced this before because I am currently unable to figure out what is happening, and I have tried the contrib.auth.logout as well as my own logout view that calls logout(request).

Thank you

**-- EDIT 1 --**

I am starting to think this could be a caching issue, but I highly doubt it.

my_app/urls.py:

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views

from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.index, name = 'index'),
    #url(r'^login/$', auth_views.login, name = 'login'),
    #url(r'^logout/$', auth_views.logout, name = 'logout'),
    url(r'^login/$', views.login_view, name = 'login_view'),
    url(r'^logout/$', views.logout_view, name = 'logout_view'),
    ...
]
```

my_app/views.py:

```
...

def index(request):  # Main login page
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
       user = request.user
       gen_prof = General_Profile.objects.get(user_id = user.id)
       return redirect('home_page', permanent = True)

    return redirect('login_view', permanent = True)


def login_view(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = LoginForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            cleaned = form.cleaned_data
            username = cleaned['username']
            password = cleaned['password']
            user = authenticate(username = username, password = password)
            if user is not None:
                login(request, user)
                gen_prof = General_Profile.objects.get(user_id = user.id)
                # Redirect to a success page.
                return redirect('home_page', permanent = True)
            #else:
                # return HttpResponse("user is None")
                # Return an 'invalid login' error message.
    else:
        form = LoginForm()

    template = loader.get_template('cloud/login.html')
    context = {'form': form}

    return HttpResponse(template.render(context, request))


def logout_view(request):
    logout(request)

    return redirect('login_view', permanent = True)

...
```

and in the templates I use the logout_view as the url for the Logout button.

**-- EDIT 2 --**

My urls.py is now this:

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.index, name = 'index'),
    url(r'^accounts/login/$', auth_views.login),
    url(r'^login/$', auth_views.login, name = 'login_view'),
    url(r'^logout/$', auth_views.logout, name = 'logout_view'),
    #url(r'^login/$', views.login_view, name = 'login_view'),
    #url(r'^logout/$', views.logout_view, name = 'logout_view'),
    ...
]
```

I am also using the @login_required decorator for my functions. I guess what I am trying to figure out is how to implement the provided login and logout views by Django along with the views I currently have.

Comment: show some codes, like `logout` view

Comment: Just edited @Bijoy

Answer (score 2):

```
return redirect('login_view', permanent = True)
```

You are using permanent redirects in your login and logout views. This means that your browser goes straight to the target page, so the server does not log the user in or out.

Even after you remove `permanent = True`, your browser may store the permanent redirect. You can test your code is workibg by using another browser.

Django comes with login and logout views. I suggest you use them to avoid this mistake or others.

Comment: Thank you for your help! I tried that but am having some trouble figuring out how to use the Django login and logout views. Please see **Edit 2** above for my changes after your comment